# 3D Carousel for Android?

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to implement a 3D Carousel selector?

Something like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [sina.com.cn](http://cache.mars.sina.com.cn/nd/bbsdigi/attachments/year_09/month_05/2/f/initial.png))</sub>
 [alt text http://www.spbsoftwarehouse.com/uploads/images/mobileshell/Screenshots/3/204.png](http://www.spbsoftwarehouse.com/uploads/images/mobileshell/Screenshots/3/204.png)

Comment: Um, could you clarify your question? Do you mean "does Android have a 3D Carousel selector"? (answer: no -- there are no 3D widgets) Do you mean "has anyone seen an app with a 3D Carousel selector"? Do you mean "does anyone know how to implement a 3D Carousel selector"? Also, a link to an image of what you consider a 3D Carousel selector to be would help

Comment: Since you answered the one, remains the second.

Comment: You would have to program it yourself I'd imagine, making use of the newly updated NDK

Comment: I hope this article can help you
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androcarousel.aspx

Comment: Can anybody guide me for it's vertical version. I have a requirement of likely but in vertical not Horizontal.

Comment: @Pentium10 Hello. Did you solved this ? I want to develop same 3D Carousel. Please share code if you solve it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The closest thing I've seen is probably [this](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html). It's a modified `GalleryView` with image transforms applied to get the effects. Applying different transforms I think you could probably do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756321/carousel-view-in-android/6065617#6065617) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4756321/203667), you might peruse the [CarouselView](http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip&can=1&q=) example code mentioned in the "[Designing Android UIs for Phones and Tablets](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGIU2JX1U5Y)" session at Google I/O 2011.

The example makes heavy use of the [Renderscript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/renderscript.html) framework, released with Android 3.0.  As such, the example code is for API levels 11 and up.  Variations of the CarouselView component were used in several of the applications within Honeycomb including Books and YouTube when creating 3D carousel effects.