# Make Android Carousel to rotate automatically

Tags: android, carousel

Im developing carousel effect for my images from this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel?msg=4664505#xx4664505xx.

My Carousel layout is:

```
 <com.example.controls.Carousel
        android:id="@+id/carousel"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:animationDuration="300"
        pj:Items="@array/entries"
        pj:Names="@array/names"
        pj:SelectedItem="0"
        pj:UseReflection="true" >

    </com.example.controls.Carousel>
```

Pls anybody tell me how to customize this carousel to rotate automatically.Thanks in Any Advance.

Comment: http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html

Comment: http://www.pocketmagic.net/2013/06/a-3d-carousel-view-for-android/#.UkUkwLyKxz8

Comment: Hi @AmitPrajapati thanq for quick reply.Those are User controlled views but I want to set them to rotate automatically.

Comment: @SHAIKAFEEZA hello. I need your help develop 3D carousel Like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2418683/1405983

Comment: @prince go through this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel?msg=4664505#xx4664505xx. and change the angleOffset in method Calculate3DPosition in Carousel.java to -180.0.

Comment: Also change return value of getCenterOfView method in Carousel.java to view.getTop()/2.@Prince

Comment: This is what i changed in method http://pastie.org/8592951# it doent give correct output.

Comment: @SHAIKAFEEZA how to reduce scroll speed ?

Comment: @Prince set like this angleOffset = angleOffset * (float)(Math.PI/-180.0f);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44312/discussion-between-prince-and-shaik-afeeza)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved My question:

Calling Rotate method in onDraw as in onTouch method.Which is:

```
  @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      super.onDraw(canvas); 

      mFlingRunnable.startUsingDistance(-180);

    }
```